# what is wrong with this SQL 3 table join

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT Schedule.*, Performers.Name, Venues.Name 
FROM Schedule 
INNER JOIN Venues ON Schedule.VenueID=Venues.id 
INNER JOIN Performers ON Schedule.PerformerID=Performers.id 
WHERE Performers.Name='Bearslap' 
ORDER BY Venues.id ASC
```

This returns all the columns from Schedule, and the Name column from Venues, but not the Name column from Performers:

```
Array (
  [id] => 10
  [VenueID] => 1
  [Day] => SAT
  [Start] => 07:00:00
  [End] => 09:00:00
  [PerformerID] => 4
  [Date] =>
  [Notes] =>
  [Name] => Timeout
)
```

switching the order of the inner joins made no difference

Comment: Can you create a SQL Fiddle to show some data and what's going on?

Comment: Something you can try, don't use `Schedule.*`. List out all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I understand this, but the problem related to the fact that I had a 'Name' column in both the Performers and the Venues tables. When I gave them unique names (PName, VName) the problem disappeared. I am using MySQL.